# Group users by year and revenue

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm learning how to query records in sql and i got stuck at one problem that i can't figure out myself.
So basically i have data base called sql_test and i have to group users based on the intervals that are -1 year, -2 years from 2016-12-31 down and based on revenue that is bigger then 2000.

I got users sorted and grouped but when i check how were they grouped by looking at order creation date it looks like my query didn't followed my conditions about interval of years.

It looks like `CASE WHEN` is only using `SUM(revenue) > 2000` and completely ignoring the interval condition.

I'm new in the SQL world, and I'm a self-learner, so don't be too harsh ;)

I work in PSQL, pdAdmin4 and server is based on PostgreSQL 15

What i have to achieve:

- Group 1: Customers with >2000 total revenue in last 1 year
- Group 2: Customers with >2000 total revenue in last 2 years

| email_id | order_number | order_creation_date | order_type | customer_segment | product_category_id | product_sku | quantity | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 194826 | 7f598909bbd4144ab23a78c3a0bda9b6 | 2016-05-28 09:47:52 | Web | Consumer | '' | 8358ab6af9a7542d380e75e839d215a0 | 1 | 178.18 |

Code:

```
SELECT email_id ,
       COUNT(email_id) as num_of_orders ,
       SUM(revenue)    AS total_money_spent ,
       CASE
         WHEN order_creation_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31'
              AND SUM(revenue) > 2000
                THEN 'Group_1'
         END
FROM sql_test
GROUP BY email_id,
         order_creation_date
ORDER BY num_of_orders DESC ;
```

Problem is that i want only users from past year from 2016-12-31 which have at least 2000 in revenue

[image]

P.S., If you recognize my post, sorry, I made another one because I implemented the wrong code and photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition can be set on `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` `CASE` clause as follows :

```
SELECT email_id, 
      COUNT(CASE
         WHEN order_creation_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31'
            AND revenue > 2000
                THEN 1
         END) as num_of_orders_group1, 
      SUM(CASE
         WHEN order_creation_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31'
            AND revenue > 2000
                THEN revenue
         END) AS total_money_spent_group1,
      COUNT(CASE
         WHEN order_creation_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' and '2016-12-31'
            AND revenue > 2000
                THEN 1
         END) as num_of_orders_group1, 
      SUM(CASE
         WHEN order_creation_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' and '2016-12-31'
            AND revenue > 2000
                THEN revenue
         END) AS total_money_spent_group1
FROM sql_test 
GROUP BY email_id
```

Comment: You are right but what if i want to have two groups?

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you check

Comment: I've edited it a bit but u helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The [conceptual] model for how a SQL query gets executed is this:

1. Form the Cartesian product of all tables in the from clause.
2. Apply any applicable join criteria (the `on` bit in the `from` clause).
3. Filter the results by the criteria in the `where` clause.
4. Partition the results by the criteria in the `group by` clause.
5. Collapse each partition into a single row, evaluating aggregate functions.
6. Filter that into the results set by applying the criteria in the `having` clause.
7. Finally, order the results set by the criteria specified in the `order by` clause.

**Note that** if you are using `group by`, the columns in the result set may only consist of

- Columns specified in `group by`,
- constants, or
- aggregate functions

So, for a single year's worth of results, you could just say

```
select email_id ,
       count(*)     as num_of_orders ,
       sum(revenue) as total_money_spent
from     sql_test
where    date_part(year, order_creation_date) = 2016
group by email_id
having   sum(revenue) > 2000
order by num_of_orders desc ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT email_id,
       COUNT(*) as num_of_orders,
       SUM(revenue) AS total_money_spent,
       CASE WHEN SUM(
            CASE WHEN order_creation_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31'
                 THEN revenue END) > 2000
            THEN 'Group_1'
            WHEN SUM(revenue) > 2000
            THEN 'Group_2'
       END as Groups
FROM sql_test
WHERE order_creation_date >= `2015-01-01`
GROUP BY email_id
ORDER BY num_of_orders DESC
```